# "Send To" from Excel without "history" showing up in Lotus Notes

Tags: lotus-notes

I am currently using Lotus Notes 8 and I want to be in Excel and send it as an attachment without a history. When I am in Excel I hit File \ Send To \ Mail Recipient (As Attachment) and it opens Lotus and I have the spreadsheet as an attachment but I get a huge "conversation" or history. Even if it is a new spreadsheet so I don't know where the "conversation or history is coming from.
It has things I have sent, received and it even had Holiday calendar entries.

How can I turn this off or keep if from happening?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll likely need to work with your helpdesk.  I'd start by refreshing your mailfile design, deleting the cache.ndk and bookmark.nsf file.